# Pascal's triangle generalized formula derivation

Tags: java, math, pascals-triangle

```java
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] argh) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            int number = 1;
            System.out.format("%" + (t - i) * 2 + "s", "");
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.format("%4d", number);
                // how this formula was derived ???
                number = number * (i - j) / (j + 1);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing I want to know is that how the formula for generating each element was derived, it works perfect but how?

```java
number = number * (i - j) / (j + 1)
```

Just want to derive such expressions in similar questions.

Comment: This is more of a maths question so might be better elsewhere; however this may help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a maths question; try https://math.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: I'm new to all this so couldn't compartmentalize it, I thought the tag **MATH** and **JAVA** would be enough, anyways I got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row of Pascal's triangle is generated by iterating through the *binomial coefficient function*, <sup>n</sup>C<sub>r</sub>:

[image]

Lets compare this to <sup>n</sup>C<sub>r+1</sub>:

[image]

The second factor on the second line is exactly the factor `(i - j) / (j + 1)` which you multiply by to obtain the next number in the row. In the code `j = r, i = n`.

Comment: @qwertyPSV no problem; however as the other guys commented, it would be much more helpful and informative (for yourself) if you had read some background information (e.g. on Wikipedia) prior to posting. Think of stackexchange as a last-resort when you are definitely stuck on anything, otherwise people here will just flame you about it :D

Comment: I did know 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdF6A.gif about this, but the only problem was, I didn't substitute it with j=r and i=n, anyways thanks for the advice too.